# Как работает mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.

Вопрос по системам управления базами данных. Не понимаю, как работает `mysql`. Есть программа-клиент - это программа, которая ПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ. Есть программа-сервер - это программа, которая ПРЕДОСТАВЛЯЕТ. Вот рисунок того, как СУБД работает в связке с PHP.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из рисунка видно, браузер посылает GET-запрос веб-серверу - "Дай мне документ `script.php`, держи еще параметр". Веб-сервер находит этот документ в папке-сайте и отдает на отработку интерпретатору PHP со словами "Вот тебе документ, отработай его + держи серверные переменные, которые я из `HTTP`-заголовка запроса браузера вытащил (`$_GET, $_SERVER`)". Программа-интерпретатор `PHP` находит в скрипте `<?php ...?>` ЗАПРОС и посылает его СУБД, которая лезет в конкретную папку-базу данных, берет оттуда какие-то данные и ВЫДАЕТ обратно программе-интерпретатору `PHP` . Получается, что интерпретатор `PHP` - это клиент. На рисунке видно, что интерпретатор PHP и сервер `mysql` находятся на одном компьютере - сервере. **Могут ли они (интерпретатор `PHP` и сервер `mysql`) быть на РАЗНЫХ компах?** **Если да, то по какому протоколу они "общаются" между собой?**

Например, браузер и веб-сервер общаются непосредственно по протоколу `HTTP` . Браузер делает запрос, который имеет вид "заголовок `HTTP`" + "тело данных (может быть пустым, если запрос идет методом `GET`)", происходит процесс передачи (опускаю момент, как именно данные передаются), а веб-сервер его получает в таком же виде. Потом веб-сервер отвечает браузеру.

**Какая программа кроме интерпретатора `PHP` может быть клиентом сервера `mysql`?**

Если я работаю с СУБД mysql в командной строке, то для работы надо зайти в программу `mysql` `monitor` - вводится `mysql.exe -uroot -p` . **Зачем вводится логин и пароль при запуске `mysql monitor`?** Еще можно ввести хост (`\h`). **Можно ли работать с сервером `mysql`, когда клиент на одном компе ,а сервер `mysql` - на другом компе?**

**Как поймать вайршарком заголовок этого протокола mysql?** хочу посмотреть, как происходит обмен данными

Comment: Указывайте данные для подключения. Хост уже будет не localhost естественно

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/overview.html

Comment: стандарт - это не учебник, а справочник. поэтому он краткий и непонятный. а еще и на английском - непонятный вдвойне

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Могут ли они (интерпретатор PHP и сервер MySQL) быть на **разных** компах?

**Да!** Обычно MySQL работает через локальную петлю, но она явлется сетевым адаптером, и ничто не мешает MySQL работать и через настоящую сеть.

Более того, по мере роста системы вынос БД на отдельную машину может быть вынужденной мерой, скажем, чтобы вместо одного сервера иметь кластер. Или... в Docker, к примеру, принято иметь контейнер с БД отдельно от контейнера приложения. А контейнеры взаимодействуют между собой по сети практически как разные машины.

> Если да, то по какому протоколу они "общаются" между собой?

**По [протоколу MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html).** Отдельного названия у него нет, т. к. сформировался он в MySQL, и хотя появились и другие БД, его реализующие, они себя позиционируют как "совместимые с протоколом MySQL".

> Какая программа кроме интерпретатора PHP может быть клиентом сервера MySQL?

**Любая,** при условии, конечно, что она может установить с сервером БД TCP-соединение (именно TCP, не уровнями выше) и может реализовать протокол MySQL.

Конечно, есть целый набор библиотек-коннекторов для разных языков, реализующий этот протокол, поэтому обычно достаточно подключить библиотеку и начинать работу. А поскольку одна из официальных библиотек-коннекторов написана на С, прицепить её можно почти к любому языку программирования.

> Зачем вводится логин и пароль при запуске mysql monitor?

Потому что БД иначе не разрешит доступ. Это ж клиент. А сервер требует представиться перед началом работы, чтобы определить привилегии клиента.

> Еще можно ввести хост (`\h`). Можно ли работать с сервером mysql, когда клиент на одном компе ,а сервер mysql - на другом компе?

Ключ `h` для того и нужен. Правда, у вас должна быть возможность дотянуться до порта, на котором работает MySQL. Сколько видел разных MySQL, по умолчанию они слушают только локальную петлю и внешние соединения не принимают. Из соображений безопасности, конечно. Это не мешает прокинуть этот порт через SSH-тоннель, где на том конце соединение будет видно, как с локальной машины. SSH относительно безопасен.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. как поймать вайршарком заголовок этого протокола mysql? хочу посмотреть, как происходит обмен данными

Comment: @Dimon нужно смотреть соединение с сервером БД, очевидно. Зная адрес и порт. Но лучше сначала почитать общее описание протокола, по ссылочке из ответа оно есть.

Comment: я о том, что, может быть, есть какие-то онлайн базы данных (куда можно что-то записывать и брать оттуда). и клиент какой-нибудь - какая-нибудь программа-клиент сервера mysql, которую я могу поставить себе на комп и "прослушать" их общение вайршарком.

Comment: @Dimon берёте MySQL Workbench, цепляетесь к нему, соединяетесь с локальным MySQL и щупаете. "Онлайн" никакой не нужен, MySQL и так работает через сеть, даром что виртуальную, в пределах одного компьютера.

Comment: как это "цепляетесь к нему"?

Comment: @Dimon следите за его соединениями.

Answer (score 2):

1. Да, интерпретатор PHP и сервер mysql могут быть на разных "компах";
2. В таком случае они будут общаться по протоколу TCP;
3. Любая программа, на любом языке может быть клиентом mysql, если имеется соответствующий драйвер для базы данных;
4. Логин и пароль требуются для авторизации и проверки соответствующих прав доступа;
5. Да, можно. Часто сервер приложения и базы данных разносят на разные хосты.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. насколько я знаю, протокол tcp - транспортный. он рубит данные на куски при отправке и собирает из кусков данные при приеме + соединение осуществляет. в заголовках tcp все поля касаются чисто "транспорта". хочу руками пощупать это "общение" между клиентом и сервером mysql - словить эти фрэймы вайршарком и заголовки почитать